# JS - Click not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, click, contains

Im trying to write this function that clicks on a link containing specific text, the only thing is the link does not lead to a new page. I just need to trigger a click so that I can execute my next function which works fine. Here's my code --

```
function Clickit() {
var TargetLink = $("a.box:contains('9')")

if (TargetLink.length)
    window.location.href = TargetLink[0].href
    }
```

This leads to infinite reloading, so I tried modifying it like this --

```
function Clickit() {
var TargetLink = $("a.box:contains('9')")

if (TargetLink.length)
    click().href = TargetLink[0].href
    }
```

But this gives a error that click is not defined. Im still learning JS so Im not quite sure what Im doing wrong. Any ideas?

Also is there a better way to write the code without using "$" or "JS" so I dont have to embed the jquery library with my extension?

Comment: Have you logged your TargetLink and tried to find out it its `undefined` or something? Add `console.log(TargetLink.length)` and `console.log(TargetLink[0].href)` before the `if` condition and check.

Comment: console.log(TargetLink.length) -- shows "1" in the console

Comment: Then something wrong with `TargetLink[0].href`. Try replacing with `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';`. This should take you to Google. What is `console.log(TargetLink[0].href)` giving you?

Comment: console.log(TargetLink[0].href) shows a blank space on the console. I dont want the link to take me to a new page though, I just want it to click the <a> tag with the specified text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/* Define the function like this: */
function clickIt(text) {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a.box')).some(function(a) {
        if (a.textContent.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
            a.click();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

/* Call it like this: */
clickIt('9');
```

---

```
/* Alternatively, you can define the function like this
 * (which uses a more straight-forward syntax to the same effect): */
function clickIt(text) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('a.box');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var a = elems[i];
        if (a.textContent.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
            a.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3089477: Always glad to help ! (BTW, awesome answers can be also upvoted (it's the small up-arrow on the left of the answer) :))

Answer (score 0):

The error says everything. you have not defined method click(). If you are trying to call jquery .click() method then you need an element reference for that something like

```
$('a.box').click();.
```

Just write a jquery method that is triggered on click of < a > having box class, have condition as below and return false if condition holds.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.box').click(function(){
            //return false if condition holds
            if($(this).text().indexOf('Google') < 0)
                 return false;
            //else default return is true page navigates to respective link
        });
    });

    <a class="box" href="http://www.google.com">Google<a>
```

if you don't wanna use jquery then following js will do the same thing.

```
    function linkClick(link){
        //return false if condition holds
        if(link.innerHTML.indexOf('Google') < 0)
            return false;
        //else default return is true page navigates to respective link
    }

    <a class="box" onclick="return linkClick(this);" href="http://www.google.com">Google<a>
```

Comment: Clciking on an anchor element can do much more than just changing `window.location.href` these days. If you want to simulate clicking on an anchor element, use its `click()` method. Note that the question is not about setting the onclick behaviour, but programmatically triggering a 'click'.